# Using node.js for a server on a websocket site

Tags: javascript, websocket, server

I have built a simple chat application using websockets as well as the node.js program.

The website at the moment only works on my own computer - if I open multiple tabs or browsers I can send messages which would appear on all the other open tabs.

I now want to publish the site on a server so other people can use it to chat from other devices.

I know how to publish this on a server, however I do not know how to publish it so it keeps working because at the moment I have to use the node.js program to run a java script file which makes it listen on a port. Obviously if I publish the site to a server, I won't be able to keep on prompting the node program to listen for the port.

So my question is - how do I publish this site to the server? Can I use node.js program with it? My server is filezilla where I transfer the files to.

Thanks

Comment: You have basically two options which will depend on the "rights" you have on your server. Most easy is to use https://github.com/Unitech/pm2 or https://github.com/foreverjs/forever but you can also make a "service" for the process (depends on your server's provider)

Comment: Filezilla is an FTP server that... serves files. How do you expect it to listen to HTTP and connect your clients between them?

Comment: Filezilla is just the app which you use to transfer files to your webserver. What is the provider of the server?

Comment: @sebilasse I believe the provider of the server is ares but I am unsure...I am a university student so I can find out for definite on Monday

Comment: You get a hosting service that supports servers written in node.js and you get a domain that you can point at the IP of your server on the hosting service.  You don't "publish" a server to another server.  Instead, you get a hosting plan that lets you "run" your own server.

Comment: @S1eym For now this question is "out of scope" of stackoverflow because you need a web server where you are able to "install things" - if it does not work with your university, you can start with a free one, see e.g. http://www.hostingadvice.com/blog/where-to-find-free-node-js-hosting/ (scroll down) - personally I am using the wonderful german "pay as much as you want" provider https://uberspace.de